# SQL union equivalent in XQuery

Tags: sql, xquery, dtd

I am given the below mentioned XML DTD and its related relational database schema :

```
<!DOCTYPE CATALOG [ 
<!ELEMENT CATALOG (TOOL | TOY)+> 
<!ELEMENT TOOL (NAME,SPECIFICATIONS+,OPTIONS?)> 
<!ELEMENT NAME (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENTSPECIFICATIONS (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT OPTIONS (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT TOY (NAME,PRICE?)>
<!ELEMENT PRICE (#PCDATA)>]>

Tools(toolid: integer, name: string, options: string) 
Specifications(toolid: integer, specno: integer, spec: string) 
Toys(toyid: integer, name: string, price: string)
```

How do I translate following SQL query into equivalent XQuery expression?

```
SELECT name FROM Tools
UNION
SELECT name FROM Toys
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you need XQuery? XQuery works on XML data, and your source is relational data. Do you need to convert it first to xml?

Comment: Edited question: added DTD information. Yes, I need XQuery.

Comment: Eh, I'm afraid I dont know DTD very well, but SQL server has a poor DTD support itself. It would help if you'd provide some example of data itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XQuery result sets are sequences which get flatted when nesting them (which equivalents the SQL `UNION`).

```
(/Catalog/Tool/name, /Catalog/Toy/name)
```

But you don't need to query both paths anyway as `<name/>` tags may only occur inside `<Tool/>`s and `<Toy/>`s, so you can simply use the expression `//name`.

Comment: Ok, Jens. I believe we can write this path expression in FLOWR expression too, correct ? How to do that?

Comment: No, you need sequence flattening at some point. A flwor expression can only loop over one sequence at a time (you could nest them, but that would equivalent a `JOIN`, not `UNION`).

Comment: Thank you, Jens, for the explanation.

Comment: You can think if FLWOR expressions like a `SELECT` statement, you couldn't fake a `UNION` with `SELECT in SQL, either.

Comment: The XPath expression given is perfectly legal XQuery, but if you have your heart set on a FLWOR expression, you can use `for $n in //name return $n`.